# affine Lefschetz and Poincaré duality for syntomic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$. Is there an affine Lefschetz theorem and Poincaré duality for sheaves represented by finite flat commutative group schemes of $p$-power order for syntomic cohomology of $X$?